# Library for parsing linux configuration file?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I am working on a Linux project. My application has a configuration file. The contents in the configuration file is not fixed ie the content in the configuration file may grow or even go down. The application doesn't know about the possible keys in the file, its all dynamic. The format for configuration file is

```
enabled = true
xxxx = QQQQ
yyyyy = WWWW
.
.
.
```

My Question is that,

1. Is there any better format for the configuration file?
2. Is there ant library to parse the configuration file?

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend looking at [toml](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml). It's friendly to humans and has parsing libraries in many many languages (including C).

Your example configuration file wouldn't even change much:

```
enabled = true
xxxx = "QQQQ"
yyyyy = "WWWW"
```

The whole list of parsing libraries is listed on the toml homepage, but for C you probably want https://github.com/ajwans/libtoml

Comment: what about glib-Key-value-file-parser